# CDI event propagation to ViewAccessScoped/ConversationScoped classes with REST Service

Tags: java, rest, jsf-2, jboss, cdi

I have a database layer, that can be accessed by `JSF and by REST`. The
backing `beans for JSF are ViewAccessScoped`. The `services for REST are RequestScoped`.

When creating an entity, from both JSF or REST, an event should be raised
to notify all possible clients (JSF, but also other clients listening e.g.
JMS events). Now a problem occurs. When I create an entity using the REST
interface the event is raised as expected.

However now `WELD raises an ContextNotActiveException:`

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active
contexts for scope type
org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped
```

I get the same problem when using the ConversationScoped annotation. This
problem occurs always when using the REST interface, i.e. whether or not I
have an JSF page open.

Below you find a more detailed stack trace starting from the point where
the event is fired.It seems like Weld thinks there is such a bean, but in
the end then can't get a context.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No
active contexts for scope type
org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ConversationScoped
    at
org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:598)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:71)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
de.dfki.asr.compass.ejb.project.OpenScenarioBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.handleEntityCreated(OpenScenarioBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
[classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at
org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:564)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:68)
[weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
```

What can I do here? Does the CODI implementation even work in this context?

Comment: No, `ViewAccessScoped` and its derivatives are all JSF specific.  JAX-RS cannot work with them.  Same with the `ConversationScoped` you're using.

Comment: @JohnAment There should be some way of making them Work Together. Is'nt it.

Comment: You could implement your own scope and integrate it to JAX-RS. But it is not so trivial to do.

Comment: You're using a custom scope from a JSF implementation.  The jAX-RS spec officially request `@RequestScoped`

Comment: [@Observes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhic.html) is the one which i am searching for :) I hope this can fix this Issue. I will try this and Update back Soon :)